# How to get a header of a clicked node of a TreeView in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

Here is my TreeView:

```
<TreeView x:Name="Tree">
   <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
         <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="TreeViewItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
      </Style>
   </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

No matter which node is clicked, in the Header Property of a sender is Header of the root of the Tree.

Comment: Get the selected item from the tree. Cast it to whatever it actually is.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. But I still don't understand why all parents of clicked treeviewitem perform this event (especially the root).

Comment: Bubbling. The children are contained within the parent. Try setting e.Handled = true.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this from the [`Source`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.routedeventargs.source?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_RoutedEventArgs_Source) of the [`MouseButtonEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventargs?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
private void TreeViewItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   var sel = e.Source as TreeViewItem;
   if(sel != null)
   {
      String text = sel.Header as String;
   }
}
```